# How do I find the amount of Ether the deployed contract on Remix IDE holds?

Tags: remix, ether

Assuming I have successfully deployed a contract on the online [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and sent Ether to the address the contract is deployed to; how do I find the amount of Ether that the contract/address now holds?

Comment: you can check the contract balance in a block explorer such as https://etherscan.io/

Comment: Presumably not if you were using remix with its default settings however: JavaScript VM runs in the browser so blocks generated are not going to be on etherscan?